# My VPS was wiped, can I still access it?

Tags: data-recovery

Someone gained access into my Ubuntu VPS via SSH, they entered rm -Rf / which wiped it and now I can't access it via SSH or SFTP. On SFTP I get the the following error:

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

And then on SSH, I try to connect to my VPS IP on Port 22, it doesn't come up with anything for ages (it should come up asking for a username) and then a op-up appears saying: Network Error: Connection timed out.

Is it possible to fix this, if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use your VPS provider's portal to either restore an image backup - if you have one - or reload it with their default image, if you don't have a backup.

If you are feeling very, very lost in the woods about this, you should contact your VPS provider's support and inquire about your options.

In practical terms, any data which was on that VPS at the time it was `rm -rf`'ed are gone for good if you did not have them backed up anywhere.